# Symfony2, how create a widget like a standalone class

Tags: symfony, widget

Let's start with basic thing, simple example is Yii. It has such thing as widgets. Standalone, configurable and callable from any place we want classes. And I'm wondering can symfony2 has the same? What it will be? Controller in bundle? Action simple (method)? Widget (twig) with parameters?

In Yii we create class (of widget), standalone, describe it and use (by calling in template). How will it look like in symfony2?

Simple example 'i want create menu navigation using widget, where it will construct html by user roles'.

Answer (score 9):

Symfony doesn't provide such a feature however you can make them yourself. They are few ways of doing it.

I'll just admit that we are talking about widgets that could do backend work (i.e. get data from DB, call an API, etc.).

### 1 - The scalable way

The use of the [render tag in Twig](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) which allows you to call a controller action from a template. It's scalable because you could use [esi tags with Varnish](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#using-edge-side-includes) (you can also implement your own caching profiles). 
As a bonus, the profiler will show details about the specific render calls in the timeline (it will look like a subset of the entire request).

### 2 - Include a template

The included template gathers the data through a Twig function call. By experience, it's a bit faster than the first solution however it's not easily scalable.

### 3 - Render through a custom TwigExtension

The twig function will get the data and call the `renderView` method of the `template` service. If you are planning on doing this, you probably want to use the first method.

### Conclusion

If you have a big website with modules/widgets that gets a lot of traffic (or "hit"): use the first solution.

If you have a small website with no support for caching: use the second solution. You'd use this solution if the module/widget is super light.

If you are thinking about the third solution... it's probably a good idea to use the first solution.

Personally, I'll always try to use the first solution and try to boost the performance one way or another. The render call in Twig has been significantly improved since the last versions of Symfony2.

Hopefully, my answer will provide you some guidelines.

Comment: You forgot about TwigExtension. That can be used as widget. With own controller and access to service container, etc.

Comment: The use of TwigExtension is my third point actually.. I'll update my answer. 
By the way, you could have validated my answer, you know, because it's actually a complete and valid answer.