# why does twig's render function create a subrequest

Tags: symfony, twig

why does twig's render function create a subrequest ? Why dont they just render the response and send it as part of the response ?

Also I can see that the rendered response appears in the browser just after the main template shows up. How does it happen ?

Answer (score 2):

I created [an answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632701/symfony2-how-create-a-widget-like-a-standalone-class/17636780#17636780) which basically goes through the different alternatives of the `render` function.

It also explains why you should be using the `render` function over a regular `include`.

I'd advise you to read the chapter about [embedding controllers in Twig](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers). An interesting quote from the doc about when you should consider using the `render` function:

> Whenever you find that you need a variable or a piece of information that you don't have access to in a template, consider rendering a controller.

TL;DR

By default, the `render` function only takes a URL (either absolute or relative).

By analogy it is like getting HTML through ajax and injecting it in the page: one request that queries a controller to get some HTML which get injected it into the page.

There are different `render` calls like `render_esi` (for support of the ESI tags) that have their own rendering strategies. If you start with the inline rendering (through the default `render` function) you will have the opportunity later on to use other rendering strategies **without** refactoring your code.

**The `render` function is meant to scale your application.**

For more details about its usefulness, let's look at the `render_esi` function.

With the `render_esi` function you can implement [ESI tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes) to use with [Varnish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_(software)).

(There are other solutions than Varnish but it's among the most popular ones)

Varnish is a caching solution that is located between your web servers and the users. Varnish will filter the response from your web servers, cache the entire page then look for these ESI tags.

If Varnish cached your page for a day but the `render_esi` function are set to be cached for 2 hours, Varnish will only query (through a URL when the cache expired) for these specific render calls instead of the entire page (which is why `render_esi` do sub-requests) and replace parts of the template with the sub-requests' response.

Caching in general is very interesting and very broad so it's hard to go over every details in my answer but I hope my answer will help you.

Caching (or cache) according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caching_(computing)):

> In computer science, a cache (/ˈkæʃ/ kash)[1] is a component that transparently stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster.

Comment: I like your answer, but as I understand, you don't need any Twig functionality to use ESI. It is a proxy (Varnish in this case) functionality, you just put ESI tags wherever you want and proxy makes requests (and caching) for that tags, so no subrequests (inside an app) are needed. I may be wrong, I never used ESI, this is just how I understand it.

Comment: You don't have to use `render` in order to use the ESI tags but you might as well use it because it's [officially documented/supported](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#edge-side-includes), convenient and provides consistency in the app, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm pointing out that statement *"with the render function you can implement ESI tags"* can be wrong. You don't use `render` for it, you use `render_esi`, as documentation says. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, I didn't phrase my response properly, I'll change that

Answer (score 1):

Render is used when you not just want to include another template snippet, but also want to execute specific businesslogic, that belongs to this template. Or in other words: When include just isn't enough, you use render.

Because render doesn't only include a template, but also executes controller logic, it is encapsuled as a subrequest.

Imagine you want to display the latest news in a box on every page of your website. If you want to solve this with an include, you would have to fetch the latest news in each of your actions and pass it to your template.

But if you use render, you just write one action for this, and put a render tag everywhere in your templates where you would like to have that news box. The render tag executes the associated controller action, renders the response, and injects it into your current template.

Because I suck at explaining, you might also want to read this part of the symfony doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, answer should sound like this:

1. Controller is pretty simple "unit" which receives request and sends response.
2. Creating sub request for rendering controller gives you more power (flexibility).

About flexibility. Look at your controller, just like it just receives request and sends response and for example, you want to somehow filter request or decorate response? Where will you put this logic? Of course, at event listeners which can use other services to solve this task.

For example, I often use parameter converters for [my controllers](https://github.com/krasun/MovieSpeech/blob/master/src/Mo/SpeechBundle/Controller/SpeechController.php#L50) (it's not about good design, just for example). So how can I use "render", with specifying just id of my entity, to render only controller without creating sub request?

If you really want just to render some data you can use "include" or create an extension. Or you can create extension to render controllers without sub request, but think about it carefully, because further you can add more logic to filtering response and so on.

I can be wrong, it's just my opinion ;)

Comment: I agree with this answer. render needs a whole Request process as it calls a Controller.